# Get facebook posts/events/news/gallery with javascript (or php) inside my website

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, twitter, flickr

I'm tryin to develop a (almost) 100% client-side dynamic website by integrating it with twitter, facebook and flickr.

I've been able so far to get the last 4 tweets (with javascript) from my client's feed, and now i was wandering if i could do the same with facebook's gallery and events from their feed.

Especially, what i need (given the facebook username/api key/whatever)

**gallery**

for each gallery in user's profile:

- get the gallery name
- get the first picture
- get the gallery url

**news/events**

for each news/event/post in user's profile:

- get the event name
- get the event text
- get the event picture (if provided)
- get the event url

I don't want to use the facebook widgets with their rendering, i just need to read the json response (if there's any) and put the data inside my website (like a preview).

Since my client is pretty rusty with "computers (cit.)" but he's (not so strangely) comfortable with facebook/twitter/flickr, i tought about a solution like this before adding a database and an admin interface to our website.

I found some resources online, so i think it's possible (in a way or another). I'd like to do it in javascript, but if it's php i won't complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this API to get photoes from the user profile
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

This is for events
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: thanks man! i didn't see those pages before because i don't have a facebook account myself! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the PHP or the Javascript API SDKs:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

respectively. Naturally you would handle the returned information differently. Both have a method called api() which can be utilised to grab the album and event objects (as mentioned in another answer):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

You can pass parameters in the methods to restrict the results returned by fields, number of items, sizes of images etc. This is outlined here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

But the issues you are going to face is that you have to authorise your "app" - think website when they use the terminology "app" - to give it permissions to access the information. This takes the form of a two step process. You have to create the app on the Facebook platform which can then access the API methods (only certain information can be got from the API methods without an authenticated app).

The second part is that the user themselves must then authenticate their facebook account against your app - this gives your app permission to access the user's information. In plain English it would go like this:

User visits your webpage; user must be logged into Facebook and must approve your app (this used to be called Facebook Connect for obvious reasons); the app and the user account are "connected"; the app can then use the api methods you've written to return information about the connected user

The beginning explanations of how to do this are here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

The only way you can access a user's (non-public) information from outside of Facebook is via a connected app and user profile.